# runtime.getRuntime.exec Freezes executing

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, cmusphinx

I'm trying to execute a .bat file in Java for creating a Language Model for Sphinx 4.

The bat file:

```
cd plugins
perl tocorpus.pl
text2wfreq < corpus.txt | wfreq2vocab > corpus.vocab
text2idngram -vocab corpus.vocab -idngram corpus.idngram < corpus.txt
idngram2lm -vocab_type 0 -idngram corpus.idngram -vocab corpus.vocab -arpa corpus.lm
sphinx_lm_convert -i corpus.lm -o languagemodel.lm.bin
```

It uses the toolkit provided by Sphinx. The process is ran by:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("plugins/lm-builder.bat");
```

The output stops after idngram2lm, just before the last line. Running this file normally from a command prompt works fine, and everything will be executed, with the proper results.

Any idea why the execution is frozen when ran in Java?

EDIT:
The CMU toolkit exports multiple files during the process, and also removes them. So looking in the Explorer window will show progress.

The output in text is retrieved by:

```
BufferedReader inStreamReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream())); 

String s= "";
while((s = inStreamReader.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

EDIT 2:
Running the code directly in Java does make it work. Although I don't think this solution can be used in the .bat file

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /K \"\"plugins/idngram2lm\" -vocab_type 0 -idngram plugins/corpus.idngram -vocab plugins/corpus.vocab -arpa plugins/corpus.lm & exit\"");
```

Comment: How do you know it's frozen? How do you get the output?

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: should it not be `Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C plugins/lm-builder.bat"); `? maybe try to add a new line after the last command in the `.bat`

Comment: I have tried your solution, but it doesn't make any difference. The first 5 commands are executed, but it still doesn't go to the sixth one.